# spinning wheels on dashboard columns - can't edit site - unknown error

Tags: error

[image]I'm getting constantly spinning wheels on columns on dashboard and can't edit the site - https://timetoshineleeds.org/ - but live site is fine. Got 'error unknown' message when going into dashboard.
Screenshot attached
Is anyone familiar with this problem?
Thanks
Rob

Comment: Check the Craft `storage/logs` folder for the underlying error message. My guess is it'll be something SSL related, but you can share the error message here if you need help interpreting it.

Comment: @Brad Bell FWIW, I'm now seeing the same thing in a Craft 2 site.

Comment: A whole bunch (~250) intermediate security certs got revoked this week, so my guess is your server is going to have one of those in its certificate chain that needs fixing https://www.mail-archive.com/dev-security-policy@lists.mozilla.org/msg13493.html